# What do tibetan door tassels symbolise?

Tags: culture, tibet

So there are these tassels on doors in Tibet. I've googled for a good hour to find out what they symbolise or are used for, but nothing concrete materializes. Some think it's a door bell, some think it's a way to ward off spirits- What are those things called, and what's the idea behind them?

[image: ex 1]
[image: ex 2]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cultural symbols.

Answer (score 5):

They are basically prayer flags, an offering to the spirits to bless & protect the house and keep evil out.  Unfortunately I can not remember their Tibetan name at the moment (but will add it later if I remember).